# I need a word for my obscure phobia for hard, smooth structures

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes, roots, phobias

If I let myself, I become upset and a bit terrified by smooth hard structures. A good example is the most perfect sphere in the world, seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMByI4s-D-Y). It's a polished sphere of solid silicon-28.

The metal cylinder held by the host later in the video also creeps me out.

A sphere of smooth concrete, granite, marble, or some other hard substance is the worst.

What's the best prefix for my -phobia?

(I think the reason for this phobia is that I slipped and whacked the back of my head against a smooth concrete surface when I was very young.)

Comment: If that fall is indeed the cause then you likely have post-traumatic stress syndrome.

Comment: I'll accept that, but I think this still qualifies as a phobia, right?

Comment: You'd have to ask a psychiatrist.

Comment: sfairesphobia is a fear of balls.

Comment: Did you watch *Phantasm* at an impressionable age?

Comment: How do you feel about ice skating? Ice skating on black ice? Does that kind of surface terrify you?

Comment: @JEL -- Oddly, ground surfaces don't bother me. Their solidity isn't as three-dimensional as that of spheres and cylinders. Blocks don't bother me either. They have "endpoints". I suppose I shouldn't have said "structures". I hadn't dissected it so much until you asked your question.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox -- If anything from that movie would bother me, it would be trepanning. :)

Comment: I've accepted Ronald's answer because he did a good job and answered first. He uses a reference I hadn't known about so far. Now that I've thought about it more and have an exact understanding of what bothers me and what doesn't, I've used that reference to find a coinage of my own: lissostereophobia. Lisso- means "smooth, polished", and stereo- means "solid, hard, 3D". It's the closest I can come with just two prefixes. "lissospherophobia" is also close but imperfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Greek an even, level, smooth; used in the sense of "flat" or "plane" would be termed as **homalo-** or **homal-**.

Perhaps you could consider this:

[**homalambulophobia**](http://wordinfo.info/unit/995)

> *noun*
>
> a fear of walking on or of touching even or smooth surfaces

Comment: I cannot find any existing word in English beginning ***homal...***. The nearest on offer is ***Hotmail***!

Comment: @WS2 - Well, close enough.  Lots of people have Hotmail-phobia.

Answer (score 0):

Fear of what is *(a)* hard and *(b)* smooth? One coinage, coming up!

Relevant ancient Greek adjectives are [λεῖος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dlei%3Dos), *smooth,* and [σκληρός](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dsklhro%2Fs2), *hard.*

Therefore, ***līo-sclēro-phobia*** or ***sclēro-līo-phobia.*** Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

> psilosclerophobia

from the Greek combining forms for 'smooth' and 'hard'.

> **psilo-**
>   Forming scientific terms with the sense ‘smooth, bare’.

and

> **sclero-**
>   occurring in scientific terms.
>   1. As combining form of Greek σκληρός hard.

(From [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/).)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an **English** word, then don't make a word from obscure Greek roots, make one from regular English roots:

**spherosiliconphobia**

or perhaps

**smooth'n'hardphobia**

Comment: Why not get rid of the -phobia part too, then? That's Greek!  So is *sphero-,* and *silicon* is Latin (despite its Greek-seeming termination). And the whole synthetic approach is to be rejected on like grounds. OP's query be damned! "Fear of what is smooth and hard!" Final answer!

Comment: @BrianDonovan I'm not opposed to words with Greek or Latin origins. But unlike *homal*, *psilo*, or *sclero*, almost everyone will recognise *sphero*, *silicon* and of course *phobia*. They may have Greek or Latin origins, but now they're just normal English morphemes.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, 'spherefear' has a disturbing ring to it--just the thing for a phobia! Chisel a space in there, 'sphere fear', and you've done an end run around downvoting neologophobes (maybe those are quasi logophobes...there might be some disagreement). Either way, though, it doesn't seem as if that sort of wonderful English compound is what the OP had in mind; nor is the 'sphere' part (structure, cylinder, sphere, surface all came into play).

Comment: @JEL Sphere fear is great!